# Getting error while running merged jtl files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to generate the report in JMeter by merging .jtl files content getting below error -

`File '/home/ajij/jmeter_tests_cli/merged.jtl' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report`

`An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Could not parse timeStamp <timeStamp> using format defined by property jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms on sample timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect`

**Note -**

If i run 2 independent jtl files then will get run successfully

**Command to execute JTL file -**

- `../Documents/apache-jmeter-5.2/bin/jmeter.sh -g merged.jtl  -o ./folder`

**JTL File content -**

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6kZ7mUj0IbT6hWS0KR3BsZVK4t6wQzj/view?usp=sharing

Quick Help will be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter's documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview):

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples **from CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

As of current latest stable version [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) generating dashboards from .jtl files in XML format is not supported so either re-run your test with the following [JMeter property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) defined:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

or review your way of "merging" the result files, if it supports CSV output format - go for it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I tried with the above format to generate the CSV but still if I separately run both csv's they give me output but on combining getting issue

Comment: Error which i got - ```An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Could not parse timeStamp <timeStamp> using format defined by property jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms on sample timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect```

Comment: I repeat your "merged" file is XML, you won't be able to generate dashboard from it, I cannot assist further without knowing how do you "merge" your .jtl files, one of ways to combine 2 .jtl files is using [Merge Results plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

Comment: Looks like there is some confusion. I tried CSV files merging after you suggested to do but it gives me the error which I added to above comment. When I run individual csv's then I get results. If you want I can share that file too with you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the XML tags? I haven't tested yet using the CSV you shared, but it might be enough removing the XML tags and merging "manually" the files, I'd merge the files by removing the second headers and the XML tags, remember JMeter process the requests by time so it will order the requests by timestamp

Comment: can you please test the file I attached? have merged the files and XML tags are also properly adjusted as per merging